# AngularJs: ng-View not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my application view is split up in public and private questions.

users can see all public questions by clicking on "Show all public" questions, and the same for private questons.

i use ng-view in my main app.html, and use the show_all.html template which takes 2 arrays (private&public questions) and does ng-repeat  to list all questions.

that all works fine.

the problem is, i have search which should basically take in the ng-model, run a search & update the view with the search results (search results returning data in the same format that the public questions and private questions JSON format is).

I'm not sure whether I'm using Ng-view the right way, or why this isn't even working.

Plunker URL: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ol3h0CHYAeZwBfLtb9Pt?p=streamer

Answer (score 1):

You need to let angular know to reprocess itself. Anything that happens outside of angular requires you to tell angular to update. So in your case add an $apply() call directly after you update the searchQuestions

```
 $scope.searchQuestions()
 $scope.$apply();
```

Here are the docs on the $apply method: 
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)